# Java Simple update button

Tags: java, database, button

I need to have a update button to update a edited textfield and save it to the database. I have created the button but have no idea on how to make it update the edited textfield and update the database automatically.

This is my code:

```
private JButton getJButtonUpdate() {
    int centralize_width = (screenSize.width/2) - 150;
    if (jButton_Update == null) {
        jButton_Update = new JButton();
        jButton_Update.setText("Update");
        jButton_Update.setLocation(new Point(centralize_width, 300));
        jButton_Update.setSize(new Dimension(150, 30));
        jButton_Update.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton_Update.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Moving on to Existing Panel!");
                if(Selected != null) {                          
                    JPanel panel = new Case_Details(frame, Analyst_ID, Selected);
                    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                    frame.getContentPane().validate();
                    frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return jButton_Update;
}
```

Comment: You have a connection with the DB. Knows how to use JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JDBC to connect your Java application to your database.

What you need to do is to have a separate class which takes care of Database stuff (known as a DAO). When you click a button, you launch a new thread and do what you need to do with the DAO in this newly created thread. This will allow the [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) to not freeze should the update operation take time.

To use JDBC with your java application you will need to use [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). To see how to use JDBC within your Java application you can start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).